# How to handle user input containing quotes (etc)?

Tags: php, mysql, odbc

I have a standard text input field. It get it's value from `$_POST` and I use it to build an SQL query (ODBC, not just MySQL, if that makes a difference (or instance, I can't use mysql_escape_string() ) ) .

The query which I am building has single quotes on the PHP and double quotes on the SQL. E.g.:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $table . ' WHERE field="' . $_POST['some_field'] . '"";
```

If the user includes a double quote in his input e.g `6" wrench` the I get an SQL error on the unbalanced string (a single quote, as in `O'reilly` gives no problem).

What's the correct way to handle this? Again, **I am using the ODBC interface, not MySQL**.

Is it just a matter of `addslashes()`? Or magic quotes?

---

**Update:** the PHP manual says of magic quotes ...

> This feature has been DEPRECIATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

(not that they suggests an alternative; in fact, it also says that magic quotes will be dropped in PHP 6)

Should the answer be to use prepared statements?

Comment: Magic quotes are deprecated because they do the wrong thing at the wrong time.  It's basically automatic `addslashes()` on everything as it comes in, rather than a destination-specific escaping of data before it heads out.  Even if it worked correctly for MySQL (which it doesn't), `addslashes` does standard SQL-escaping all wrong -- in standard SQL, quote chars are escaped by doubling them up, not by adding a backslash.

Comment: You mention `mysql_escape_string()` however that function has been depreciated, if and when applicable use `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`odbc_prepare`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-prepare.php) and [`odbc_execute`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-execute.php) like PDO

Comment: +1 Sigh! Thanks. I *know* that you are right; just wish I had done it from the start. Now I have a few 100 places to change. Thanks very much for confirming that.

Answer (score 3):

Use PDO [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).  It [supports](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php) ODBC

Answer (score 0):

Even easier... why not just use htmlspecialchars?

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

I mean, it's faster, and I'm assuming that the reason why your giving users a data field that allows them to use quotes is because your going to print that data back out at some point. Which is still doable, and you don't have to change around where you store your data.

Comment: +1 thanks for posting. I'm not quite sure what you mean by "you don't have to change around where you store your data" (sorry, I'm a n00b)

Comment: err. doesn't that just do a stright translation?  So, I would be searching for a match on 6&quote; wrench

Comment: because this function has nothing to do with databases. it's **html** specialchars, not mysqlspecialchars. go figure